# China Postdoctoral system application processing time

Tags: peer-review, application, postdocs, china

how much time does it take for China postdoctoral system once we submit the application in system online?

Comment: The answer depends on various factors, your field, research interests and  nationality/political background. The CCP owns the final decision. No one can give you a definitive answer.